# Redis source code, (size&(sizeof(long)-1)) in the zmalloc.c

Tags: c, redis

I am learning the Redis source code , and in the zmalloc.c,

```
 size_t zmalloc_size(void *ptr) {
 void *realptr = (char*)ptr-PREFIX_SIZE;
 size_t size = *((size_t*)realptr);
/* Assume at least that all the allocations are padded at sizeof(long) by
  * the underlying allocator. */
 if (size&(sizeof(long)-1)) size += sizeof(long)-(size&(sizeof(long)-1));
 return size+PREFIX_SIZE;
}
```

I am confused with

```
if (size&(sizeof(long)-1)) size += sizeof(long)-(size&(sizeof(long)-1));
```

what's the effect of it? Memory padding?Then why sizeof(long)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be to include the memory padding with the assumption that all allocations are padded at the sizeof(long) (as said by the comment).

Pseudo-code example:

```
size = 6 // as an example
sizeof(long) == 4
size & (sizeof(long) - 1) == 6 & (4 - 1) == 6 & 3 == 2
size += 4 - 2
size == 8 // two bytes of padding included
```

I'm pretty fresh in C though so you should probably not take my word for it. I'm not sure why one can assume that the underlying allocator will align at the size of long, perhaps it's only a decent approximation that is sufficient for zmalloc_size's use-case.